# How to remove a portion of objects in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

This would take me a minute in Photoshop, but can't get it to work in Illustrator.

How can I remove a portion of one object over another in order to create a "hole" or "counter" within the bottom object?

Image 
[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked up any tutorials? Showing some effort will likely get you better answers. Welcome to GraphicDesign!

Comment: Hi, yes, worked on this for a day, went through tutorials. I was cutting, masking, grouping, paths, etc, close, but no cigar. Just could not find the answer. There seem to a zillion more options in Illustrator vs PS with text. Two different worlds as I'm learning. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After creating the letters "SE".

Step 1:

Right click the letters and select create outlines.

Unite them using the path finder. (shift + ctrl + F9) or windows-> path finder.

[image]

Step 2:

Then draw the circle.

> Make sure the circle is in front by right click the circle select
>   arrange ->bring to front (ctrl+shift +])

[image]

Step 3:

Now by selecting the two objects select Exclude from the Path finder panel.

[image]

Now ungroup the object (shift + ctrl + G) or right click the object select ungroup.

Step 4:

Change the color of the object after ungrouping them to green and orange like you want it.

[image]

Thanks
Digiscape Gallery

Comment: Wow, most awesome response. I have to move mentally from bitmaps to vectors. This seem to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If the S and E aren't one shape, select them both and select 'union' (might be called 'unite') from the pathfinder menu so that it's one shape.

You now have two shapes, the circle and the SE glyph. Select them both and go back to the pathfinder options and choose 'exclude'.